# How to control order in calculating shortest path of a network in r by time?

Tags: r, social-networking

I have a network where each edge has the time it entered the network as an attribute
for example

```
f=c("a","b","a")
t=c("b","c","c")
g=graph.data.frame(data.frame(f,t))
E(g)$time=c(1,2,20)
get.shortest.paths(g,from="a",to="c",mode="all")
[[1]]
[1] 1 3
```

Which is A->C. 
I want it to return A->B->C as the shortest path, or rather quickest path.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `weights` to `get.shortest.paths`:

```
get.shortest.paths(g,from="a",to="c",mode="all",weights=E(g)$time)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Alternatively, if you specify a `weight` edge attribute, you don't need to formally specify this in the call.

```
E(g)$weight <- c(1,2,20)
get.shortest.paths(g,from="a",to="c",mode="all")
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: that still throws up a problem. If E(g)$weight=c(1,2,3) then it sees a->c and a->b->c as the same length though the latter is quicker and what i want

Comment: @user3068071 - I don't follow. If `weight == c(1,2,3)` then `A->C` is 3 and `A->B->C` is 3 so it selects `A->C` because that is fewer stops on the way.

Comment: Yes but these are the times the edge appear. which is why i had it as the attribute time. So 'E(g)$time=c(1,2,3)' A->B->C arrives at c at time 2 but A->C arrives at C at time 3. I've been messing with it just now and can  calculate 'get.shortest.paths(g-E(g)[E(g)$time>2],from="a",to="c",mode="all")' but in my full graph with lots of time increments this is slow

Comment: Hmmm... that is more complex. Could you work backwards by finding which edge ending in "c" has the minimum time?

Comment: I also have trouble when, for example, edge A->B exists at time 2 and B->C exists at time 1. So there is no path between A and C, my approach has been to combine the graphs at each time point and stop when c is reached but I don't know how to work in cases like this